# Can you override the file permissions for the heap dump produced by -XX+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, jvm

On Linux when using `-XX+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` the hprof file produced is owned by the user under which the java process is running and has permissions of 600.

I understand that these permissions are best security wise but is it possible to override them?

Comment: anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can start the JVM with

```
java -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="chmod g+r java_pid*.hprof" {mainclass} {args}
```

The command runs after the heap dump is created. This will allow group read access to all heap dump files in the current directory for example.

Comment: Getting the following error: "Error: Could not find or load main class g+r Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: g+r"

Answer (score -1):

The `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError` parameter doesn't work for me with spaces in the command on JRE 7(1.7.0_72).  But pointing to a shell script (without spaces) does. Example:

> -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="/path/to/shell/script.sh"