# Give read permission to others for HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError file .hprof on generated

Tags: java, linux, heap-dump, hprof

I start my java with these arguments

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/log/${SERVICE}_`date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S`.hprof"
```

When heap dump occurs, the `.hprof` file has `-rw-------` (600) permission, which can't be read by other users.

How do I make these files generated with `644` permission?

**Attempt**: 
I tried passing this `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError="chmod 644 *.hprof"` but got the error:

```
Improperly specified VM option 'HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError=chmod'
```

What should be the correct syntax? Thank you

Comment: Did your check your umask settings? Typically applications use that umask settings that the environment drops on them?

Comment: @GhostCat other generated logs have correct `644` though. E.g: gc.log, nohup.log

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html says that  *HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError* is an **option**. What makes you think that you can pass a **shell command** to that in the first place?!

Comment: @GhostCat I followed this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484559/can-you-override-the-file-permissions-for-the-heap-dump-produced-by-xxheapdump . However, if that's not the way, any suggestion for the original question?

Comment: Did you try the second answer, pointing to a shell script? ( beyond that, that is the thing with these -XX options: they are subject to change at any point. it is possible that this worked with earlier versions of java, but doesnt work with the specific jvm implementation you are using )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the issue, the correct args list should be

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='chmod 644 *.hprof' -XX:HeapDumpPath=/log/${SERVICE}_`date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S`.hprof"
```

Since I put everything inside double quote and then put in `JAVA_OPTIONS`, the inner quotes should be single